# Accessing the database simultaneously

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, simultaneous

I'm developing the server side for a mobile app with Google App Engine and JDO in Java, and I have some problems accessing simultaneously to the database.

The app that I'm doing is a chat, and when two persons are accessing the database simultaneously, one of the messages is lost. I think that is because one of the two accesses are being done before the other which is before it's saved in the database, and that's why one of the messages are lost.

Do you know some solution for this? Something like get the access to the same registry in the database and put them in a queue or a stack for accessing lately.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

**Conversation.java:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class Conversation 
{
    @PrimaryKey  
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private Long idUser;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "conversation")
    private LinkedList<Message> messages;

    public Conversation(Long idUser) 
    {
        this.idUser = idUser;

        messages = new LinkedList<Message>();       
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public LinkedList<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

**Message.java:**

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class Message 
{
    @PrimaryKey  
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
    private Key id;

    @Persistent
    private Conversation conversation;

    @Persistent
    private String text;

    @Persistent
    private String hour;

    public Message(String text, String hour)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getText() 
    {
        return text;
    }

    public String getHour() 
    {
        return hour;
    }

    public Key getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Conversation getConversation() {
        return conversation;
    }
}
```

**Save the Messages:**

```
final PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();      

String strQuery = "select from " + Conversation.class.getName() + " where id == " + id;
persistenceManager.getFetchPlan().setGroup(FetchGroup.ALL);
final Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery(strQuery);

try 
{
    List<Conversation> conversations = (List<Conversation>) query.execute;

    Conversation detached = null;
    detached = persistenceManager.detachCopy(conversations.get(0));

    detached.getMessages().add(message);
    persistenceManager.makePersistent(detached);
} finally {
    persistenceManager.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some code that demonstrates the problem you're having. We can't diagnose your problem without seeing it first.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don`t know you need them, because it`s very simple. There it is.